# How to use multiple java file, each file in each folder?

Tags: java, file, visual-studio-code, command-line, directory

I am new in java and I coding on vscode. I create 2 .java file like picture below:

[image]

And these are each file:

main.java:

```
package program;
import sth.another_one;

public class main{

    public static void main(String args[]){
         another_one a = new another_one();
         a.func();
        System.out.println("main");
   }
}
```

And this is

another_one.java:

```
package sth;

public class another_one{
    public void func(){
        System.out.println("From another one");
    }
}
```

When I put both of them the same folder it run normally, but if I separate them like this and run on cmd -> it return like this:[image]

I try all command like:

> javac -cp ".;C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test\java\sth" main.java

> javac main.java

> javac -classpath main.java

I don't know why it did worked, please help me solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you overcome this issue, you are sure to encounter another after having a big project.

Use an IDE (Integrated Development Environment). It will take care of many things for you and you don't have to worry about linking/building problems. Through IDEs, you focus on developing and not on the background of compiling and class files.

There are so many good ones out there

1. [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipseide/)
2. [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)
3. [NetBeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid naming classname as `Main`, and use `quick fix` to import instead of manually adding import sentence. You should get right result:

[image]